# WCF Named Pipes AddressAlreadyInUseException

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I am using named pipes to communicate between multiple different apps. I have two named pipe hosts which I am trying to get to listen on different addresses.

If I start either app on its own it will run. When i run the second app it will throw and exception telling me that the address is already in use.

```
System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: 'Cannot listen on pipe name 
'net.pipe://dfb679124c82453888842928c37c6dae/' because another pipe endpoint is 
already listening on that name.'
```

The two services are not using the same address.

I have even setup one of the services with the following code:

```
       Host = new ServiceHost(
            this,
            new Uri[]
            {
                new Uri("net.pipe://"+Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))
            });

        var binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();

        Host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), 
                       binding, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

In this code I am generating a random address when the service is created and it still throws the AddressAlreadyInUseException.

I am not using any config configuration to setup the named pipes, everything is code based.

What am I doing  wrong?

Comment: The reason for this was because if forgot to add localhost at the start of the named pipe. I think I was getting the error becaue WCF couldn't bind because localhost was missing. The error itself was incorrect.

Comment: Here's some more light reading, but it sounds like you've identified the issue. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2011/03/22/named-pipes-in-wcf-are-named-but-not-by-you-and-how-to-find-the-actual-windows-object-name/